# Custom services from IServiceProvider in D365

Tags: c#, dynamics-365

We have recently starting building applications using D365.  This is a shift from java where we used spring for dependency injection.  It seems that `IServiceProvider` does dependency injection, but I haven't found any way to make it work with our home grown services.

We have code that looks like this:

```cs
public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
    IOrganizationServiceFactory factory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
    IOrganizationService service = factory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);
     
    // ... do stuff ...
}
```

and I want to add in the following line:

```cs
MyHomeGrownService myHomeGrownService = (MyHomeGrownService )serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(MyHomeGrownService));
```

However, I don't know how to register `MyHomeGrownService`; nor have I found much documentation on the topic.

Without proper dependency injection, developers have resorted to using `new` in the code which is makes proper unit tests near impossible.

How can I register custom services?

Answer (score 0):

For now, I created a delegating `IServiceProvider` implementation which I use to wrap the given `IServiceProvider` in every plug-in call.  That custom implementation is aware of our services and will create those when ask.  Everything else, it delegates.

I tried to make the delegating `IServiceProvider` to be fast, but I have yet to try it in a live system, so I don't know how performant it is or isn't.